# parsing multiline nested tokens from a file in perl

Tags: regex, perl, lex

I have a file that looks line this:

```
Alpha          27600  
Beta        1  
Charlie       true  
BEGIN Delta      
    BEGIN Epsilon        Setting High  Hook 50  END
    BEGIN Foxtrot        Corp 71  END
    BEGIN "Jelly Bean"        Corp 88  END
END
BEGIN Hotel    
    Height                 25  
    Lawn  85
END
```

Basically it is several key/value pairs separated by one or more spaces. The tricky part is the BEGIN/END blocks that might be nested and might span multiple lines. I need to go through the file and take some action based on what follows the BEGIN. For example, if it's Delta, i might need to process each of the sub BEGIN lines where as if it is Hotel, i can skip that completely.

I looked at Parse::RecDescent a little bit but wasn't sure how to make it handle the BEGIN/END situation properly. Speed isn't as important as having a an easier to understand and maintain solution.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I liked Miller's solution, but then looking over the data realized why I didn't just split on whitespace. Some of the labels have whitespace in them. Added "Jelly Bean" label in above data file to reflect that.

Comment: So what's your expected output?

Comment: Is there any limit to how deeply the `BEGIN/END` blocks can nest?

Comment: @Avinash Raj - based on different labels and sections I will further process the key/value pairs.

Comment: @md4 - So far, I think it just nests two deep, but in the future it could be more.

Comment: @Bromide - I have added a comment to Miller's answer to address the quoted spaces problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse the whole data structure, and filter out sections you don't need after the fact:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

my @tokens = parse_line( qr{\s+}, 0, do { local $/; <DATA> } );

my %hash;
my @levels = \%hash;

while ( defined( my $key = shift @tokens ) ) {
    if ( $key eq 'BEGIN' ) {
        push @levels, $levels[-1]{ shift @tokens } = {};

    } elsif ( $key eq 'END' ) {
        pop @levels;

    } else {
        $levels[-1]{$key} = shift @tokens;
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%hash;

__DATA__
Alpha          27600  
Beta        1  
Charlie       true  
BEGIN Delta      
    BEGIN Epsilon        Setting High  Hook 50  END
    BEGIN Foxtrot        Corp 71  END
    BEGIN "Jelly Bean"        Corp 88  END
END
BEGIN Hotel    
    Height                 25  
    Lawn  85
END
```

Outputs:

```
{
  Alpha   => 27600,
  Beta    => 1,
  Charlie => "true",
  Delta   => {
               "Epsilon"    => { Hook => 50, Setting => "High" },
               "Foxtrot"    => { Corp => 71 },
               "Jelly Bean" => { Corp => 88 },
             },
  Hotel   => { Height => 25, Lawn => 85 },
}
```

Comment: I updated my data set in my question since some labels might have spaces in them. If I can't work out an elegant way, I may just use yours and kludge something in to deal with the quoted spaces.

Comment: Replace the top section with: `my $raw = do { local $/; <DATA> }; my @t; push @t, $1 || $2 while ($raw =~ /"([^"]+)"|(\w+)/g);` (or at least until Miller comes back with a better idea - his perl-fu is stronger than mine).

Comment: @md4 - I used your line, but changed \w+ to [\w.]+ since there are decimal numbers in places as well as things like last.name

Comment: To work with quoted words, just use the core library [`Text::ParseWords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html).  My solution is updated for the modified question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd hack something up with [Parser::MGC](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC) (though perhaps I'm biased because I wrote it).

Using a nested scope of its `scope_of` method will easily handle those `BEGIN`/`END` markers for you.